# How to map dataframe rows into a custom object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class, bioinformatics

I am trying to map the individual rows of a dataframe into a custom object. The dataframe consists of multiple molecules that interact with a specific target. Additionally, multiple molecular descriptors are given. A slice is given below:

[image]

Now i need to map each instance into a Molecule object defined as something like this:

```
class Molecule:
    allDescriptorKeys = []

    def __init__(self, smiles, target, values):
        self.smiles = smiles
        self.target = target
        self.d = {}
        for i in range(len(Molecule.allDescriptorKeys)):
            self.d[Molecule.allDescriptorKeys[i]] = values[i]
```

Where the *allDescriptorsKeys* class variable is set from outside the class using

```
def initdescriptorkeys(df):
    Molecule.allDescriptorKeys = df.keys().values
```

Now I need a class function *readMolDescriptors* that reads in the molecule descriptors of a single molecule(row/instance). To use it later on in an external method to loop over the whole dataframe .I guess I need something like this:

```
def readMolDescriptors(self, index):
        smiles = df.iloc[index]["SMILES"]
        target = df.iloc[index]["Target"]
        values = df.iloc[index][2:-1]
        newMolecule = Molecule(smiles, target, values)
        return newMolecule
```

But of course this is not a class function since the *df* is defined outside the class. I have a hard time wrapping my head around this, probably easy, problem. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to build a class from which you build a new instance for each row of the dataframe, and after that you want to get rid of the dataframe and play with those Molecule instances alone. Consider this:

```
class Molecule:
    
    def __init__(self, data_row):
        ''' data_row: pd.Series. '''

        self.smiles = data_row['SMILES']
        # more self.xxx = data_row['xxx']
        self.d = data_row.to_dict()
```

With this you can create an object of Molecule using a data row. For example,

```
molecules = [Molecule(data_row) for index, data_row in df.iterrows()]
```

To access a certain descriptor (e.g. nAT) value from the first molecule, you may do

```
print(molecules[0].d['nAT'])
```

although you can choose to define more dedicated method with the class to handle access like that.

Ofcourse, to build something like `readMolDescriptors`, below is my version.

```
def build_molecule_from_dataframe(df, index):
    return Molecule(df.loc[index])
```